# SSRS - Aging Calculation by Identifying Values in Column Grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I am trying  to achieve the following in SSRS:

[image]

Basically, to calculate aging column whenever my Date Field in Status B grouping is NULL.

Would anyone be able to help please? or point to a question that is similar?

(I've tried searching but I can't seem to get something that I can grasp)

edit #1 (20160712) - The data I have is row based :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do this in the SQL that is called by your report:

Make the Aging column a `CASE` Expression that returns NULL if `StatusB` is not null, or returns the `DATEDIFF()` between `GETDATE()` and `StatusA` if `StatusB` is null.

The same functionality is available in an SSRS expression if you prefer.   You would use an `IIF()` instead of a `CASE`, and use `TODAY` instead of `GETDATE()` in the `DATEDIFF()`.

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I should have been clearer.

The data I get is row based and I am using a Matrix Table to perform a pivot like grouping on the columns to show the date per status.

Comment: That's fine, using your current query as a CTE or derived table, you can write an outer query that applies the logic in my answer.